# Cron job not starting

Tags: linux, cron

The following cron job works fine:

```
*/1 * * * * /path/to/script
```

But this does not start:

```
0 23 * * * /path/to/script
```

This confuses me a lot. I do not get any error messages when setting up the cron job, but the second cron job just will not start?

It is the same script that is being run so it can not be any errors in the script.

Comment: When did you expect it to start? It is configured for 23:00, I just want to make sure that this was your original intention.

Comment: it should be configured for 23:00, I then test it by changing the computer clock.

Comment: What distribution and which version is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration is fine, but it looks like your testing method is a bit flowed. Read the comments of this bug report to see if it may relate to your problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cron/+bug/274631

Comment: yes, that was the problem. in my version of ubuntu it seems that the cron time does not change until reboot if system clock is changed. great thx!